Missing $ inserted. Problem with equal sign

We have  \cota                      $=   -    \bigg(\dfrac{\sin A } {1 - \cos A} \bigg)$    \\
        %  $\therefore$               $  \bigg(\dfrac{\sin A }{\cos A -1} \bigg)       = - \cota $      
            \therefore               $  \bigg(\dfrac{\sin A }{\cos A -1} \bigg)       = - \cota $  


        


Where to put the $ symbol before the equal sign. If before it is math mode. Also the open brace large one seems to have a space gap.

I had a lot of trouble with this for some reason could not get the missing $ issue to go away

All of those needs to go in math mode. Please read a decent introduction to latex and how it handles math.

\cota is predefined as a \newcommand ... elsewhere

neither \therefore nor \cota is in the latex format. \therefore you may or may not be getting from amssymb. \cota i have no idea. snippets aren't useful, especially when they use commands-we-know-not-what-they-mean. please provide a proper minimal example which we can compile to reproduce the error or problem you want help with. and also take @daleif's advice and read a basic introduction to latex. (and, yes, I know you've been a member of tex se for longer than I have.)

Is this a valid:  $\therefore ...... end of math equations $

how can we tell you that in isolation? all we can say is that it will sometimes be valid and sometimes not. it depends on what comes before it.

That is the MWE . actual real example.

The  $( \cos A + 1)$ term is cancelled:\   % this is the line before the MWE

%\newcommand{\cota}{$\cot\dfrac{A}{2}$}

please read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that. that is not an MWE or an MNWE. I cannot use it to reproduce the error you mention. I cannot use it to reproduce the output you want help correcting. whether it is real or not is neither here nor there.

if you aren't sure where to find a reliable basic introduction, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/. but the wikibook (which is probably the highest rated answer) is not the best - scroll down to find more reliable resources.

It is not a MWE as it is not compilable as is. Nobody knows the definition of the commands you show if you don’t provide a compilable example that has a document class, relevant packages and definitions.

TeX gives more information about missing $ error. Read this information carefully. You can see the line where the problem is and the point at the line is shown by TeX too.
Moreover, if you define \cota as $\cot ...$ and use it in the math mode (at the end of your third line) then the first $ before \cot closes the math mode and \cot macro is processed outside the math mode. This macro is defined as \mathop{\rm cot}. The \mathop control sequence is TeX primitive allowed only in math mode. But TeX is outside math mode in this case, so it prints error missing $ and it inserts the $ before \mathop.

I can see no reason for using inline math style, which is initiated and terminated with $ symbols, to typeset the two-line material. Instead, do use a gather* environment, which employs display-style math mode by default.

About the code: (i) Observe the use of \biggl and \biggr instead of just \bigg, to help TeX with the fine points of spacing around delimiters. (ii) Use \textnormal{...} rather than \text{...}, just in case the expression gets typeset inside, say, a theorem-like environment that italicizes text-mode words. (iii) As gather* processes the contents in display-style math mode, there's no need to type \dfrac instead of just \frac.
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'gather*' environment
\usepackage{amssymb}    % for '\therefore' macro
\newcommand\cotA{\cot\frac{A}{2}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\textnormal{We have } \cotA = - \biggl(\frac{\sin A}{1-\cos A}\biggr) \\
\therefore \biggl(\frac{\sin A}{1-\cos A}\biggr) = - \cotA
\end{gather*}

\end{document}

